# Ramifications of a computer from organisation A joining the domain of organisation B

Tags: windows, domain

We are a small company who have some of our employees sitting at parter organisations, what we specifically do is not important for this question.

A new employee has received a new Win10 laptop, which is joined to our domain. But now the external organisation, where the new employee will be based, wants the computer to be part of their domain.

Since this is all new to us, what are the ramifications if we allow our computer to join an external domain?

Comment: While Joe answered, I would clarify that it's difficult for us to really know how your organization and the other one manage your domains/computers/policies/etc. so we can't really answer in any great capacity.  If you've never done this in the past with other partners, then part of this is a question of governance and a discussion with the partner on "why" etc.  One big ramification to understand is who is responsible for the upkeep and security of the device in case it causes issues at the partner site like introducing a virus, etc.  To me, this is a sit down with the partner first.

Answer (score 2):

What are the ramifications?

The computer will fall under the purview and control of the other organization. Other than that, I can't think of anything. It's just a computer.

Comment: This should be easy to test though. Take any computer that is not part of their domain and try to use it like they intend for any purpose in their org. O365 may be a bit of a pain but I suspect most will be ok.

Comment: +1 in concept - but I commented above...like Greg stated there could be lots of things both from a technical and political aspect depending on the orgs.  You are correct, but the answer is simplified based on the limited info from the OP.